# Problem during SVN checkout: German umlauts are not being converted properly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, checkout

I have a very annoying problem when trying to checkout some code from an internal repository using SVN.

The repository is massive, it has thousands of files and in several of them, we use German umlauts.
When I do the checkout, if I try to build the code, I get an error that says "Ungültiges Zeichen”, that means that a character is not valid.

When I checked the code, instead of display the correspondent umlaut (ä, ö, ü or even ß) the system replaces it to �, the Unicode variant.

I checked my System's codepage, and it is correct: ACP  REG_SZ  65001 (This is the UTF-8)
I checked the system's language, and it is German, my keyboard is also in German.
I tried using SVN direct from the command line, but the error still persists.
I tried updating Tortoise SVN and Installing the German LanguagePackage, but the error still happens.

None of my coworkers have this problem, so I am quite lost.

If a project does not have any of those characters (ä, ö, ü or ß) it will compile correctly, so I am guessing it is something very specific.

I also could not find anything very helpful on Google.

Can anyone help me with that?